# How to make j2 to evaluate substitution inside a var value

Tags: ansible

I have the following in my config j2 template:

```html
{% set interface = vars['wireguard_' + item + '_interface'] -%}

{% for key, option in interface_required_keys.items() %}
{{ option }} = {{ interface[key] }}
{% endfor %}
```

some of `interface[key]` values are `{{ lookup('file', 'some_file') }}` which are not being expanded by ansible and put into resulting config file just like that: `{{ lookup('file', 'some_file') }}`. How can I make j2 evaluate substitution inside `interface[key]`?

Comment: `ansible -m debug -a "var=hostvars['bind']"` is an ad-hoc command, not sure if you can use `group_vars` with it. Trying this `some_var` in a playbook works, the variable gets evaluated during runtime. your need is to use it in ad-hoc ansible, or in an ansible-playbook?

Comment: @ilias-sp I need to use it in ansible-playbook but it also does not expands `supposed_to_expand`. My playbook generates config file with `"{{ lookup('file', './file_with_value') }}"` instead of `file_with_value` contents.

Comment: it works fine on my pc, i get the `some_var.some_subvar.supposed_to_expand` populated with the contents of the file. please keep in mind the lookup plugin executes on the host the playbook is running.

Comment: @ilias-sp I've tried to substitute a variable defined in inventory without lookup: `supposed_to_expand: "{{ inv_var }}"` but it also does not expand.

Comment: i am going to provide in 3 minutes the minimum testable code in an answer, along with its results to make sure we are doing the same thing.

Comment: @ilias-sp thanks to your example I've realised that Ansible does substitution for my variables and problem is with j2 template generating config file. I've updated my question with an actual problem.

Comment: could you add in your question the `interface_required_keys` variable? it would help having it for testing the problem :) if you run a `debug` task with the var and add the output in the Q would be enough

Comment: @ilias-sp actually interface_required_keys are hard-coded here: https://github.com/adamruzicka/ansible-wireguard/blob/master/templates/wgX.conf.j2

Comment: @ilias-sp debug task with `wireguard_wg0_interface` shows expanded variable but j2 template renders variable value without expansion even if I use `|safe` filter.

Comment: hmmm, it works OK for me, i will update the answer to be aligned and see if i am doing something different than you

Comment: Andrey, please check the updated answer

Comment: @ilias-sp thanks! the problem is that template gets `interface` by evaluating `{% set interface = vars.get('wireguard_' + item + '_interface', {}) -%}` which reads values without substitution. Now I should find a way get interface dynamically (depending on `item` value) and still be able to evaluate its values as templates.

Comment: i see what you mean... i think i will stop here, good luck with it!

Answer (score 1):

so, here is the code tested, file by file:

**test.yaml:**

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:

  tasks:
  - name: print var
    debug:
      var: some_var.some_subvar.supposed_to_expand
```

**group_vars/all.yml:**

```
---
some_var:
  some_subvar:
    supposed_to_expand: "{{ lookup('file', './file_with_value.txt') }}"
```

**file_with_value.txt:**

```
files_contents_here
```

no inventory file for this test.

**playbook execution result:**

```
[http_offline@greenhat-29 test2]$ tree
.
├── file_with_value.txt
├── group_vars
│   └── all.yml
└── test.yml

1 directory, 3 files
[http_offline@greenhat-29 test2]$ ansible-playbook test.yml 
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [print var] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "some_var.some_subvar.supposed_to_expand": "files_contents_here"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

[http_offline@greenhat-29 test2]$
```

we can see that the `some_var.some_subvar.supposed_to_expand` was evaluated and got the contents of the local file as intended.

is this similar to what you have prepared too?

---

**UPDATE:**

regarding the j2 issue: the loop in j2 file will try to print the `interface[key]`, so i simulated that one of the keys of this dict variable has value from a `lookup` (defined it in the `group_vars` file, the `address` key).

files used:

```
[http_offline@greenhat-29 test2]$ tree
.
├── config.j2
├── file_with_value.txt
├── group_vars
│   └── all.yml
└── test.yml

1 directory, 4 files
[http_offline@greenhat-29 test2]$ cat test.yml 
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:

  tasks:
  - name: run template
    template:
      src: config.j2
      dest: /tmp/config.out

  - name: print var
    debug:
      var: interface
[http_offline@greenhat-29 test2]$ cat group_vars/all.yml 
---
some_var:
  some_subvar:
    supposed_to_expand: "{{ lookup('file', './file_with_value.txt') }}"
interface:
  address: "{{ lookup('file', './file_with_value.txt') }}"
  private_key: value_defined
[http_offline@greenhat-29 test2]$ cat config.j2 
{% set interface_required_keys = { 'address': 'Address', 'private_key': 'PrivateKey' } -%}

{% for key, option in interface_required_keys.items() %}
{{ option }} = {{ interface[key] }}
{% endfor %}[http_offline@greenhat-29 test2]$
```

**result:**

```
[http_offline@greenhat-29 test2]$ ansible-playbook test.yml 
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [run template] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [print var] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "interface": {
        "address": "files_contents_here",
        "private_key": "value_defined"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

[http_offline@greenhat-29 test2]$ cat /tmp/config.out 
Address = files_contents_here
PrivateKey = value_defined
[http_offline@greenhat-29 test2]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ilias-sp, finally got to a solution.
The problem is that `` gets doc without values expansion.
If I obtain `interface` dict using `lookup` it's values are being correctly expanded:

```
{% set interface = lookup('vars', 'wireguard_' + item + '_interface') -%}
```